# Variables of the same dictionary in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I try to manipulate a dictionary in python but it effects all the rest instances

```
a={'a':1,'b':2}
b , c = a, a
b['a']=5

print "A:" ,a 
print "B:" ,b 
print "C:" ,c
```

the output:

```
 A: {'a': 5, 'b': 2}
 B: {'a': 5, 'b': 2}
 C: {'a': 5, 'b': 2}
```

how can I change only 'b' ??

Comment: You need to copy the dictionary. A, B and C all point to the same object.

Comment: This what I ask for..how do that

Comment: `import copy`, `b = copy.copy(a)`